# Sqlite VACCUM locks the database?

Tags: sqlite

I need to run a VACCUM in a large Sqlite database.
It locks the original database to write from other connections during the vaccum process?

I'm using database WAL format. But I'm not sure if I can corrupt my database inserting into database while other process is vaccuming.

Comment: Refer to https://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html